# R installation warning

Tags: r, installation

I am trying to install `R` from source code in my Ubuntu 14.04. I ran `./configure` but that shows some warning-

```
..........................................
.........................................
config.status: creating tests/Examples/Makefile
config.status: creating tools/Makefile
config.status: creating src/include/config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
config.status: executing stamp-h commands

R is now configured for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

  Source directory:          .
  Installation directory:    /usr/local

  C compiler:                gcc -std=gnu99  -g -O2
  Fortran 77 compiler:       gfortran  -g -O2

  Default C++ compiler:      g++   -g -O2
  C++98 compiler:            g++  -g -O2
  C++11 compiler:            g++ -std=gnu++11 -g -O2
  C++14 compiler:              
  C++17 compiler:              
  Fortran 90/95 compiler:    gfortran -g -O2
  Obj-C compiler:         

  Interfaces supported:      X11
  External libraries:        readline, curl
  Additional capabilities:   PNG, JPEG, NLS
  Options enabled:           shared BLAS, R profiling

  Capabilities skipped:      TIFF, cairo, ICU
  Options not enabled:       memory profiling

  Recommended packages:      yes

configure: WARNING: pcre < 8.32 is deprecated
configure: WARNING: you cannot build info or HTML versions of the R manuals
configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of vignettes and help pages
configure: WARNING: neither inconsolata.sty nor zi4.sty found: PDF vignettes and package manuals will not be rendered optimally
```

Texlive 2017 is also installed in my system. I want to full featured `R`. Now, what can I do for fixing the warnings?

Comment: You can install R from the repository. You don't need to compile it from sources.

Comment: Apart from @m0nhawk’s comment, aren’t most of the warnings pretty self-explanatory? Install pcre ≥ 8.32, install inconsolata.sty and install zi4.sty; and maybe make sure that any other requirements are met.

Comment: @KonradRudolph would you give me the installation command of these package `e.g. sudo apt-get install pcre`?

Comment: Although I have installed `libpere3` and `libpcre3-dev` using `apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev`, the warning is occurred.